# References to the theory of Diffrence Equations

Tags: probability-theory, recurrence-relations

I was going through some problem in Nicholas Privault's "understanding Markov Chains". To compute the average game duration in the gambler's ruin problem, he starts with an inhomogenous difference equation. The method of solution reminds me heavily about the strategy for differential equations, where one uses a linear combination of homogenuous and particular solution.

Is there a reference to a uniqueness and existence for difference equations?

I am explicitly asking for reference, not solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference I have is "Introduction to Difference Equations" by Samuel Goldberg. He addresses existence and uniqueness in section 2.3.